# linear Independence of three vector functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

are the below vectors linearly independent?

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}t\\0\\t\\\end{bmatrix},and \space \begin{bmatrix}t^2\\0\\t^2\\\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am told they are, but am confused how to show that.  I thought the coefficients would be $c_1 = t^2$, $c_2 = t$, and $c_3 = 1$; but wouldn't that mean dependence instead of independence?

Comment: so if it is just coefficients, they need to be real numbers? Meaning the above is LI, as there are no $c_1$,$c_2$,$c_3$ that make the above 0 (aside from all equal 0).

Comment: @Aryadeva “The coefficients ... are coefficients” is tautological. No doubt you meant “the coefficients are ... _constants_”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are linearly independent. Assume that scalars $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \Bbb{R}$ satisfy

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \alpha\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}t\\0\\t\end{bmatrix}+\gamma\begin{bmatrix}t^2\\0\\t^2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2\\0\\\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2\end{bmatrix}$$
for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$. This is equivalent to $\alpha + \beta t + \gamma t^2 = 0, \forall t \in \Bbb{R}$. This quadratic polynomial is zero so all coefficients must be equal to $0$, meaning $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$.

The point is that coefficients $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \Bbb{R}$ are constant, they don't depend on $t$.

Comment: Thats the answer I posted first. I deleted it. But then I read this and it confuses me https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-exponentials/MIT18_03SCF11_s35_3text.pdf

Comment: @Aryadeva The point is that $$\{f_1,f_2\} \text{ linearly dependent } \implies \{f_1(t),f_2(t)\} \text{ linearly dependent for all } t \in \Bbb{R}.$$
The converse doesn't hold in general; it holds when $f_1, f_2$ are solutions to some ODE system.

Comment: But here the wronskian is zero for all $t$..

Comment: @Aryadeva Yes, so $\{f_1(t), f_2(t)\}$ is linearly dependent for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$. As shown above, this does not imply linear dependence of $\{f_1, f_2\}$.

Comment: It's not really clear. As i said I started to answer as you did the vetors are linearly independant but that short intro to Wronkian made me confuse

Comment: @Aryadeva Your answer is fine now. The Wronskian is used in the sense $$W(f_1,f_2)(t) = 0 \iff \{f_1(t),f_2(t)\} \text{ linearly dependent}.$$
Therefore if $W(f_1,f_2)(t) = 0$ for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$ it still isn't enough to conclude that $f_1= \lambda f_2$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I rolled back my answer. Thank for your time and explanation +1

Answer (score 1):

Now, they are not linearly independent, since, for instance,$$t\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}t\\0\\t\end{bmatrix}+0\times\begin{bmatrix}t^2\\0\\t^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}t\\0\\t\\\end{bmatrix} \space \begin{bmatrix}t^2\\0\\t^2\\\end{bmatrix}$$
You can show they are linearly independant on $\mathbb R$ by proving that:
$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=0 \implies c_1=c_2=c_3=0$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}  1 & t &t^2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & t & t^2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Or more simply ( which is true):
$$c_1+c_2t+c_3t^2=0 \implies c_1=c_2=c_3=0$$
Where the coefficients  $c_i$ are numbers not functions.

Comment: i thought even with determinant 0, you still need the constants to be the same for all values of t for it to be dependent?

Comment: Of course the coefficients $c_i$ must be constants not variable or functions.

Answer (score 0):

If there were c1 and c2 and c3 that made this vectors dependent, you would have that $c1+c2.t+c3.t^2=0$ for each t which means that c1,c2 and c3 are zero. You should consider c1 and c2 and c3 as cofficients.

Comment: so the $c_i$s have to be in $R^n$?

Comment: No , when they ask you that some vectors are dependent or not, all the cofficients come from a field.

Comment: If you do not know what is an field is, Just consider that c1,c2,c3 come from R